# aws static website SSL wont work unless doing /index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS to host my website (S3 + Cloudfront) I have issued an AWS SSL certificate, but I am having an issue,

In S3 bucket, I have put the index page as "index" - the file name is saved as "index". The ssl covers both *.mydoamin.com and www.mydoamin.com , however, when I go to mydomain.com / www.mydomain.com

It is loading an older version of the "index" file and the SSL isn't secure due to the older file version having an http not https url link in the code.

When I do www.mydomain.com/index ... the website shows the updated file and the SSL says secure.

Any suggestions? I have waited 24 hours (default TTL wait time) and the error still persists

Comment: did you try by manually creating invalidation in cloudfront.

Comment: What do you have set as the `Default Root Object` set as in Cloudfront?

Comment: @KevinSeaman - I have, mydomain.cloudfront.net as the default root object

Comment: The root object should be a file, like index.html, not a url.

Comment: @hephalump look at the wrong place, root file is index , thats how its also saved in the S3 bucket